# Union on Associations (Kernel Kill)

Tags: bugs, associations, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

Perhaps `Union` on `Association`s is not being encouraged since `Join` is preferred given `Key`-`Value` shadowing.

```
Join[<|a -> 1|>, <|a -> 1|>]
```

> <|a -> 1|>

```
Join[<|a -> 1|>, <|a -> 2|>]
```

> <|a -> 2|>

... although doing so by a complete kernel kill seems a tad drastic?

```
Union[<|a -> 1|>, <|a -> 2|>]

(* i.e. don't evaluate if you don't want to lose current definitions *)
```

Comment: At first pass, shouldn't `Union` do the same thing as `Join` on `Associations`?

Comment: Reproducible crash confirmed in 10.1.0 under Windows.

Comment: This is a bug and has been fixed in version 10.2 which should be available very soon.

Comment: @ilian Do you know when the bug first appeared?  I would like to mark it in this post if possible.

Comment: @ilian Ok, (error message or same output as Join)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard 10.1.0 @Ronald Monson It will return unevaluated since it is not specified how the associations should be merged, but one could use `Merge` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting [ilian's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88165/14303#comment-240236) as an answer.

This bug has been fixed in version 10.2.0.

```
$Version
Union[<|a -> 1|>, <|a -> 2|>]
(* "10.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 6, 2015)" *)
(* <|a -> 1|> \[Union] <|a -> 2|> *)
```