# Is there an idiomatic way to determine whether an `Association` is a subset of another?

Tags: associations

I would like a way to tell if every key-value pair of an `Association` is contained in another. For instance, `f[<|c -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>]` should evaluate `False`, but `f[<|a -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>]` should evaluate `True`.

The functions `SubsetQ` or `ContainsAll` ought intuitively to do what I want, but they turn out only to operate on the values of an `Association`, not the key-value pairs.

Currently the best I have is `SubsetQ @@ Normal@*List@## &`. Is there a nicer (preferably in-built) way to do it than that, preferably which doesn't involve casting the whole lot to `List`s? It's the kind of thing I'd expect there to be a built-in function for, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: It may be possible to abuse JoinAcross for this purpose, but what you did with SubsetQ is so much more clear than that ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
associationSubSetQ[x_Association, y_Association] := 
    KeyIntersection[{y, x}][[2]] == y

associationSubSetQ[<|a -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>]
```

> True

```
associationSubSetQ[<|c -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>]
```

> False

---

### Alternative

Another method would be

```
associationSubSetQ[x_Association, y_Association] := 
    Keys[#] === Values[#] &[KeyMap[x, y]]
```

This works because `KeyMap` maps x over the keys of y, which gets you

```
<|x[keyY1]->valueY1,x[keyY2]->valueY2 ...|>
```

which reduces to

```
<|valueY1->valueY1, valueY2->valueY2 ...|>
```

if and only if y is a subset of x (otherwise you get `Missing` in some positions).

The `Keys[#] === Values[#] &` part then checks whether the vector of keys equals the vector of values. This works because both `Keys` and `Values` keep the order of the keys and values, respectively.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: @szabolcs To catch cases where the value in one of the association keys is an undefined symbol?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I meant.

Comment: Depends on what the OP wants it to do. If you leave it as is the answer may be <|a->1|>==<a->xyz|> which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was thinking of `associationSubSetQ[x_Association, y_Association] :=  Keys[#] === Values[#] &[KeyMap[x, y]]` instead.

Comment: That last one is devious! :-)

Comment: Actually, `Intersection` seems to work in the way I want, which seems a bit neater than `KeyIntersection`. Do you see a problem with `f = (#2 === Intersection@##)&`?

Comment: @Patrick `Intersection[<|c -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>]` repeatably crashes the 10.1.0 kernel under Windows.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, under Mac OS on 10.2.0 it outputs `<| |>`.

Comment: @PatrickStevens apparently a fixed bug; see: [(88165)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88165/121)

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work:

```
f = Complement[#2, #] == <||> &;

f[<|c -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>] 
f[<|a -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>]
```

> ```
> False
>
> True
> ```

Comment: Do you know of any reason why `Complement` should work on `Association`s in this way, `Union` does not, but `Intersection` does? Is there something special about `Union`?

Comment: @Patrick No, I think it is just the spotty implementation of these functions at this point.  The developers are apparently being pushed to add more and more functionality with less and less of it actually being release-ready, which is makes me sad.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm looking into why `Union` and `Intersection` are seemingly inconsistent on `Association`.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you.  I much appreciate the work you are doing on these issues, I just wish you were getting more help.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Tyte. Also look at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsAll.html type functions which should but not yet have `Key` counterparts eghttp://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59237/missing-keygroupby

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Re: "pushed to add more and more functionality with less and less of it actually being release-read" =  "technical debt"

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different from the other answers:

```
f[Association[args__], Association[args2__]] := ContainsAll[{args}, {args2}]

f[<|c -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>]
(* Out: False *)

f[<|a -> 1, d -> 2|>, <|a -> 1|>]
(* Out: True *)
```